# Can multiple flavours/applicationId use the same google-services.json?

Tags: android, firebase

Can I make multiple flavours with different applicationId connect to the same Firebase Project and the same Application ? 
These apps doesn't really differ (one has disabled some features), so I don't want to manage them separately.

To be clear: **I know that I can use separate google-services.json for each flavor, but it's not what I want**. I want to use the same google-services.json for two different flavors with different applicationId: com.my_app.flavor1 and com.my_app.flavor2

Comment: The answer here worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45713394/1213112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put `google-services.json` in the `app/src/main` folder, all flavors would use that one. If you wanted a specific flavor to use a different one, you'd put the file in `app/src/myFlavor`.